# Не работает keyboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, клавиатура

Вот мой код.Не могу понять,почему не работает?

```
from tkinter import*
from functools import partial
import keyboard
write=keyboard.write
press=keyboard.press_and_release
button='⚀⚁⚂⚃⚄⚅❶❷❸❹❺❻❼❽❾❿➀➁➂➃➄➅➆➇➈➉➊➋➌➍➎➏➐➑➒➓❌⟸➗⟳⟹⛇⛪⏳☀⛱⚒⛥⛈⛟⚙⨸✍⏰⏱☔✟⚗⚑♔❣❤♕♖♗♘♙♚♛☕☂❄➔➕➖➘➙➚➛➜➝➞➟➠➡➢➣➤➥➦➧➨➩➪➫➬➭➮➯➰➱➲➳➴➵➶➷➸➹➺➻➼➽➾♜'
button=list(button)
n=1
root=Tk()

def com(a):
    global write
    write(a)
def cordinat(n):
    x=50
    y=50
    inr=15
    str_str=((n//inr)+1)
    if    (n%inr==0):
        str_str-=1
    nomer=n%inr
    if  (nomer==0):
        nomer=15
    xc=(nomer-1)*x
    yc=(str_str-1)*y
    return xc,yc

for i in button:
    globals()[f"button{n}"]=Button(text=i,font="Arial 15",command=partial(com,i))
    x,y=cordinat(n)
    globals()[f"button{n}"].place(x=x,y=y)
    n+=1
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Все прекрасно работает, просто проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку, функция вызывается моментально, и когда `keyboard` печатает текст - в фокусе находится окно вашего приложения, поэтому вписывать текст некуда.

Comment: Спасибо действительно так.Вы не можете пожалуйста подсказать как можно решить эту проблему.

Comment: Разве что только подсказать)

Можно сделать задержку после нажатия кнопки, чтобы можно было успеть переключить фокус на нужное окно, но это неправильно. В идеале нужно сделать так, чтобы работало как экранная клавиатура, то есть чтобы на ней не было фокуса. Это надо гуглить, я поищу, если найду - дополню ответ

Comment: Я уже до этого додумался но приходиться так каждый символ, а это не очень удобно.Ещё раз спасибо что помагаете

Comment: Вообщем, я ничего путного не нашел. Думаю, стоит задать где-нибудь отдельный вопрос, что-то вроде "Как сделать экранную клавиатуру на Python", обязательно отметив свойство фокусировки на другом окне. А применить полученную информацию к доработке этого кода. Пока что все, что придумал